# What is malaise in the following passage?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

**The malaise of innovation**

> DG Research commissioned a group of experts to study the impact of the concept of the knowledge society on citizens (‘Taking European Knowledge Society Seriously’). A central question of this project was the nature of and possible answers to the malaise that civil society feels towards certain techno-scientific innovations, particularly in relation to their objectives, the social changes they bring and the underlying risks. The research was conducted very openly by groups that included not just experts, but also students of ‘hard’ sciences and human sciences (sociology, philosophy and law students), citizens who had expressed their interest in taking part in the study and trade unions. The conclusions of this study center in particular on the tendency to focus exclusively on a knowledge society motivated by a frenzied race for innovation and efficiency imposed by globalization, which, its authors state, poses a serious problem of acceptance by society. The study explores many avenues for having civil society experience the dynamics of innovation as a collective and diversified undertaking, democratically shared by all.

What do they mean with malaise of innovation? What is malaise here?

malaise means a general feeling of discomfort, illness, or unease whose exact cause is difficult to identify

Comment: Have you looked up the word in the dictionary.  Please paste the  definination and say how it doesn't fit here.

Comment: malaise means a general feeling of discomfort, illness, or unease whose exact cause is difficult to identify.But I do not understand what malaise of innovation is.why does society have malaise towards innovation?

Comment: Many people feel uncomfortable anxious or fearful about new things that change their lives, especially if they don't understand or trust them. That is the malaise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as the dictionary defines, in a slightly figurative way.

"A feeling of discomfort or unease, about new technology" in particular the social or environmental effects of new technology.  For example someone might feel uneasy about mobile phones because of how they track your movements. Or uneasy about plastic bags because they pollute the environment.

Comment: thank you for your answer could you explain me this sentence if possible The conclusions of this study center in particular on the tendency to focus exclusively on a knowledge society motivated by a frenzied race for innovation and efficiency imposed by globalization, which, its authors state, poses a serious problem of acceptance by society.

Comment: not really, It means what it says.  If you have a specific question about that sentence can you ask another question?   Try to break it down, remove the "extras" like "in particular" or "its authors state", check the dictionary, look at the context.  Read for comprehension.

Comment: "the conclusion of this study on tendency to focus only on a knowledge society motivated by a race for innovation cause a problem" does it mean racing for more innovations is causing problem and society is unwilling to accept it because of the reason you mentioned?